# How should I use the proper charset for my vcard?

Tags: android, python, csv, character-encoding, vcf-vcard

i had an issue with my smartphone so i needed to export my adress book check and modify each phone number. I have some contacts with spanish characters (á ñ ü) and when I try to look at  my new vcf homemade file Thunderbird doesn't recognices.
I've read some questions related but I don't figure where is the point to me.

This is the schema:

1. I take a **vcf** from phone.
2. I open it to Thunderbird and fix the wrong information.
3. I export to **csv** file.
4. I make my code to get the **csv** to a **vcard(vcf)** again

So:

- in old vcard there are some fields that:

  NOTE;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:=6E=6F1=61=74=61=63=69=
- in csv file all the characters and info are right.
- in new vcard:

  1. opened in **blocknotes**: it shows the charset tag and shows **legible string**
  2. opened in **thunderbird's adressbook**: doesn't show fields with charset issue.

This is my code opening and parsing the info:

```
def hasRareChar(string):
'''
Checking if strange characters are there.
'''
    c = False
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i == len(string): break
        if string[i] in 'ñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚäëïöüÄËÏÖÜ':
            c = True
            break
        i += 1
    return c

def codeTag(string):
'''
adds the charset thing 
'''
    return string[:-1] + ';CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:'


def parseCsvVcard(cab, linea):
    '''
    sets string info into dict structure,
    csv to vcard: I need to re-order and re-name the fields.
    '''
    # dict splitting info
    d = {}
    for x, y in zip(cab, linea.split(',')):
        # print x + ':' + y
        d[x] = y
    # ------------------------------------------------
    # dict for VCARD format.
    d2 = {}
    # NAME COMPOSITION - using hasRareChar(str) codeTag(str)
    '''
    check = ['First Name' in d.keys(),'Last Name' in d.keys(),'Display Name' in d.keys(),_
             hasRareChar(d['First Name']),hasRareChar(d['Last Name']),hasRareChar(d['Display Name'])]
    tags = ['','','','N:','N:','FN:']
    for index, i in enumerate(check[3:]):
        if i: tags[index+3] = codetag(tags[index+3])
    tags = ['','','',if check[3]: '',,]
    '''
    # First and Last Names --------
    codeNames = hasRareChar(d['First Name'] + d['Last Name'])
    strNames = d['Last Name'] + ';' + d['First Name'] + ';;;'
    if not codeNames:
        d2['N:'] = strNames
    else: d2[codeTag('N:')] = strNames

    # DISPLAY NAME ----------------
    if d['Display Name'] != '' and not hasRareChar(d['Display Name']):
        d2['FN:'] = d['Display Name']
    elif d['Display Name'] != '':
        d2[codeTag('FN:')] = d['Display Name']
    else:
        if not codeNames:
            d2['N:'] = d['First Name'],d['Last Name'] + ";"
        else: d2[codeTag('FN:')] = d['First Name'],d['Last Name'] + ";"
    # -------IF TOWER:-----------------------------------------
    for i in d: # PARA EL RESTO DE CAMPOS NO VACIOS
        if i not in ['Display Name', 'First Name', 'Last Name'] and d[i] != '':
            if 'Primary Email' == i : #detecto que campo es
                tag = 'EMAIL;HOME:'
            if 'Secondary Email' == i:
                tag = 'EMAIL;WORK:'
            if 'Mobile Number' == i:
                tag = 'TEL;CELL:'
            if 'Home Phone' == i:
                tag = 'TEL;HOME:'
            if 'Work Phone' == i:
                tag = 'TEL;WORK:'
            if 'Web Page 1' == i:
                tag = 'URL:'
            if 'Notes' in i:
                tag = 'NOTE:'
            if hasRareChar(d[i]): # compruebo si debo codificar el TAG
                tag = codeTag(tag)
                d2[tag] = d[i].decode() # WHAT SHOULD COME HERE ???????????
            else: d2[tag] = d[i] #asigno
    return d2
# ----------- MAIN CODE DOWN HERE ---------------------
#  -- csv file opened to a string variable ------------
csvFile = open("contactList.CSV",'r')
readed = csvFile.read()
csvFile.close()
lines = readed.split('\n') # split lines
# separated header and info rows.
head = lines[0].split(',')
# la informacion
lines = lines[1:]
# ----------------------------------------
# new text construction with parse function.
texto = ''
for x in lines[:-1]: # last is a blank record
    y = parseCsvVcard(head,x)
    #print y
    texto += 'BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:2.1\n'
    #iterando cada campo se escribe
    for index in y:
        texto += str(index)+str(y[index])+'\n'
    texto += 'END:VCARD\n'
# ----------------------------------------
# WRITE TO NEW VCARD FILE
with open("please RENAME.vcf", 'w') as vcard:
    vcard.write(texto)

print '----- File Created: please RENAME.vcf -----'
print '----- Check it for proper information.'
```

It seems that I maintain the charset tag reference, python takes the correct characters (python makes most things correct :) but I don't make any transformation in the string variables. **Beware the question inside the code, I readed some other posts and maybe the point is there).**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I managed it:

I make this every string I need to ensure it will be displayed:

```
strNames.decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

so this is added to the tag in vcard (now the function in the code above has changed:

```
;CHARSET=UTF-8:
```

Now in notepad there are this kind of chars:

```
Ã± Ã©
```

but

> 1. Thunderbird shows everything properly.
> 2. ¡¡ And it works too in my Android Phone !!

The code above only needs the charset `.decode().encode()` fixes and the `IF TOWER`  modification to work. Also check the file names to use your own. I post the code which worked for me here:

> #### [csvToVCARD.py](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5373401/code/csvToVCARD.py)

Comment: Thanks for the down-vote, It was a bit lost but I tried it again. I hope some comments about charsets handling in python and blocknote.